# Adding addition decimal places to a column

Tags: r, dplyr

I don't know why I'm finding this so difficult, but I'm trying increase the number of decimal places in my printed output.

The current output looks like this:

```
rating
 0.98
 0.99
 0.87
```

I would like it to look as such:

```
 rating
 0.9800
 0.9900
 0.8700
```

I tried `df %>% mutate(rating = round(rating, 4)` but that just returns the same results with only two decimal places.

Comment: `options(digits=4)`. If you're rendering to some "fancy table" (e.g., `knitr::kable`, `formattable`, etc), then you will need to review docs specific to that package to get it to display what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could use `sprintf` or `format` to do the formatting to return a `character` column

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
     mutate(rating = sprintf('%.4f', rating))
#  rating
#1 0.9800
#2 0.9900
#3 0.8700
```

---

With `tidyverse`, the print.tbl behaves slightly differently by doing its own formatting.  So, if the question is about the way it is printed, we need to change the options for printing tibble

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(rating = c(0.98, 0.99, 0.87)),
      class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```